# Piecewise Continuous Fredholm Kernel

Tags: operator-theory

Suppose I have a ``Fredholm equation of the second kind" with kernel 
$$
K(x, y) = 1[x \geq u]k(x, y)
$$
where k(x, y) is continuous.

Let $f_n(x)$ be a smooth continuous approximation of $1[x \geq u]$ which converges uniformly to $1[x \geq u]$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Is it possible to show that 
$$
\phi(t)= \int_a^bK(t,s)\phi(s)\,\mathrm{d}s.
$$
only has the trivial solution if $\tilde{K}(x, y) = f_n(x) k(x, y)$ only has the trivial solution for each $n$ sufficiently large?